# How to make AWS ASG do nothing when instance count is between min and max

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, terraform

We're using Terraform to launch ASGs for most of our AWS EC2 instances. The problem is that once in awhile we want to do some extra work before terminating an instance; for example: decommissioning a node from a cluster before the EC2 instance it was running on is terminated. If we were just to lower `min` == `max` (our default) then an instance gets terminated and we can't run a graceful decommission.

Instead what I've tried is lowering `min` to the new desired value (example: 6) and keeping the `max` at the old value (example: 10), what happens in this case is that the `desired` value stays at 10 (the `max`) and terminating the EC2 instance causes a new one to be launched by the ASG. NOTE: we are not setting the Terraform  `desired_capacity` setting at all.

If I set `desired_capacity` manually, I risk the ASG terminating a node that has not been gracefully decommissioned so I don't think that's an option for me.

What I'd ideally like is for the ASG to do nothing when the current EC2 Instance count for that ASG is between `min` and `max` and let me manually terminate instances. Obviously if the count goes below `min` I'd still like the ASG to launch a new EC2 Instance.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposed solutions:

**Option 1**: Your ASG should be created with instance protection **ON** - [Terraform docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html#protect_from_scale_in)

In this case, we could have next sequence of operations for instance decommission:

1. Perform decommission of particular instance(s)(remove data from it(them))
2. Reduce *count* of ASG's size by desirable value
3. Apply Terraform state
4. Remove protection flag from decommissioned instances: `aws autoscaling set-instance-protection --instance-ids <instances_ids> --auto-scaling-group-name <asg_name> --no-protected-from-scale-in`

**Option 2**: Your ASG was **not** created with instance protection.

In this case, we could have next sequence of operations for instance decommission:

1. Add protection flag on all instances of ASG: `aws autoscaling set-instance-protection --instance-ids <instances_ids> --auto-scaling-group-name <asg_name> --protected-from-scale-in`
2. Perform decommission of particular instance(s)(remove data from it(them))
3. Reduce *count* of ASG's size by desirable value
4. Apply Terraform state
5. Remove protection flag from decommissioned instances: `aws autoscaling set-instance-protection --instance-ids <instances_ids> --auto-scaling-
   group-name <asg_name> --no-protected-from-scale-in`
6. (Optionally) Wait until ASG shrinks to desirable size and remove protection flag from other instances

Comment: I think that `Option 1` is the safest and most straightforward way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible ways to achieve what you want:

**Option 1:** Suspend Auto Scaling Processes

You can put the Auto Scaling group's processing "on hold" while you are making your adjustments.

For example, you could try:

1. Pause Auto Scaling processing: `aws autoscaling suspend-processes --auto-scaling-group-name MyGroup`
2. Decommission and terminate your EC2 instances,
3. Adjust the desired count manually,
4. Resume Auto Scaling processing: `aws autoscaling resume-processes --auto-scaling-group-name MyGroup`

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/suspend-processes.html

**Option 2:** Use Auto Scaling Lifecycle Hooks

Using Lifecycle Hooks, your launched and/or terminating EC2 instances are given an opportunity to do an initial or pre-termination processing. For example, you can have the hook notify the terminating instnce that it is about to be terminated, and it can decommission itself from your cluster.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html

Comment: For other users following this path: be *extremely* careful suspending and resuming an ASG, when resuming I got into a strange state where the `desired` count jumped to the `min_count` and the ASG promptly turned off two instances. You can suspend a specific process such as terminate: `aws autoscaling suspend-processes --auto-scaling-group-name my-asg --scaling-processes Terminate`